# Rclone Failed to sync: googleapi: Error 403: We're sorry, but this service is not available in your location, forbidden

Tags: location, rclone

I want to backup my files into google drive using [rclone](https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_config/) by this command:

```bsh
sudo rclone sync  "/media/so/ACAC8B5FAC8B2346/Company Informations/مدارک شرکت GSH/اداری (copy)"  gsh:Company_Informations/office_files  --checkers 3  --log-file /home/so/Desktop/trash/rclone_sync.log -v --transfers 3
```

So i get this error:

```
Failed to sync: googleapi: Error 403: We're sorry, but this service is not available in your location, forbidden
```

So entire log file is this kind:

```
2019/12/30 21:16:04 Failed to create file system for "gsh_email:drive": drive: failed when making oauth client: error opening service account credentials file: open ss: no such file or directory
2019/12/30 21:52:45 ERROR : : error reading destination directory: googleapi: Error 403: We're sorry, but this service is not available in your location, forbidden
2019/12/30 21:52:45 INFO  : GCS bucket Company_Informations path office_files: Waiting for checks to finish
2019/12/30 21:52:45 INFO  : GCS bucket Company_Informations path office_files: Waiting for transfers to finish
2019/12/30 21:52:45 ERROR : GCS bucket Company_Informations path office_files: not deleting files as there were IO errors
2019/12/30 21:52:45 ERROR : GCS bucket Company_Informations path office_files: not deleting directories as there were IO errors
2019/12/30 21:52:45 ERROR : Attempt 1/3 failed with 1 errors and: googleapi: Error 403: We're sorry, but this service is not available in your location, forbidden
2019/12/30 21:52:45 ERROR : : error reading destination directory: googleapi: Error 403: We're sorry, but this service is not available in your location, forbidden
2019/12/30 21:52:45 INFO  : GCS bucket Company_Informations path office_files: Waiting for checks to finish
2019/12/30 21:52:45 INFO  : GCS bucket Company_Informations path office_files: Waiting for transfers to finish
2019/12/30 21:52:45 ERROR : GCS bucket Company_Informations path office_files: not deleting files as there were IO errors
2019/12/30 21:52:45 ERROR : GCS bucket Company_Informations path office_files: not deleting directories as there were IO errors
2019/12/30 21:52:45 ERROR : Attempt 2/3 failed with 1 errors and: googleapi: Error 403: We're sorry, but this service is not available in your location, forbidden
2019/12/30 21:52:46 ERROR : : error reading destination directory: googleapi: Error 403: We're sorry, but this service is not available in your location, forbidden
2019/12/30 21:52:46 INFO  : GCS bucket Company_Informations path office_files: Waiting for checks to finish
2019/12/30 21:52:46 INFO  : GCS bucket Company_Informations path office_files: Waiting for transfers to finish
2019/12/30 21:52:46 ERROR : GCS bucket Company_Informations path office_files: not deleting files as there were IO errors
2019/12/30 21:52:46 ERROR : GCS bucket Company_Informations path office_files: not deleting directories as there were IO errors
2019/12/30 21:52:46 ERROR : Attempt 3/3 failed with 1 errors and: googleapi: Error 403: We're sorry, but this service is not available in your location, forbidden
2019/12/30 21:52:46 Failed to sync: googleapi: Error 403: We're sorry, but this service is not available in your location, forbidden
```

So what is your recommendation to solve this problem?

Comment: You ask two completely different questions, so you should separate those I believe into tqo questions. But regarding `rclone` it SOUNDS like the country you're in doesn't work with Google's services (because `We're sorry, but this service is not available in your location` means that Google denies your country access).  You're going to have similar problems with VPNs and such if you're located in Iran

Comment: Thanks @Thomas_Ward, i asked the question about VPN problem [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1199734/keepsolid-vpn-unlimited-dont-connect-to-its-servers)

Comment: Please edit your current question to remove the part about VPN.

Comment: @vanadium, i edited the question ...

Answer (score 1):

403 with that message indicates Google does not offer this service to your country or location.

Given the geolocation from your VPN question placing you in Iran, this is likely due to sanctions in place on your country and Google is abiding by the law of those sanctions and disallowing Iraq access to this service.  Unfortunately, this is Google’s decision and there is nothing we can really do to assist you in this matter other than suggest you use a VPN (which may or may not also forbid Iraq from connecting)