# KeepSolid VPN Unlimited doesn't connect to its servers

Tags: networking, vpn

I have problem with my [KeepSolid VPN Unlimited](https://www.vpnunlimitedapp.com/en/downloads/linux) in Iran.

When I am trying to connect to its server, it's attempting to connect; but, it can not successfully do it.

Here is an example:

[image]

I would like to know how I could find why this happened?

Comment: Then the issue is likely country filtrations in place either by your ISP or the VPN provider.  As I indicated in the other question, due to various sanctions and such in place, sometimes companies have to block access to things based on region.  This makes sense that it applies to VPN(s) as well, especially given that Google is 403-ing (your other question) because your country is not permitted to access their services - VPNs are possibly in the same boat.

Comment: So this question must be closed by this answer, if yes please answer by typing this comment  and i approve it.

Comment: also from Iran. how can i download VPNUNLIMITED in ubuntu 20.04?